# How to find the least number with maximum trailing zeroes when multplying with numbers containing 4 or 7 only!

Tags: algorithms, contest-math

Example:

15 -> 15*4=60 - minimum number with max trailing zeros

125 -> 125*4*4=2000

400 -> 400 will be the answer as its the minimum number with max trailing zeros.

Can you think of any other cases? The Given number is to be multiplied only with **numbers that have only 4 or 7 as their digits**

**Edit:**
I tried the approach of finding the number of times 5 divides that number. But I don't understand how I might be able to check for trailing zeroes after multiplying by **any number** containing 4 or 7

Comment: What is meant by "trailing zeros"?

Comment: @BolzWeir Zeroes at the end

Comment: @BolzWeir it means the number of zeroes at the end of any number. Example: no of trailing zeroes is three in 203000

Comment: You might want to see how many 5s you can factor out of numbers. For example, $15=5^1\times3$, $125=5^3\times1$, and $400=5^2\times16$.

Comment: So is $9765625 \times 4\times 4\times 4\times 4\times 4$ allowed?

Comment: yes @Henry. The multiplication can occur any no of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a trailing zero, you a factor of $2$ and $5$ in the product.  To get $n$ trailing zeros, you need factors of $2^n$ and $5^n$ in the product.  Your multipliers cannot supply any factors of $5$ (Why?), so the maximum number of trailing $0$'s will be the number of factors of $5$ in the number you start with.  Then if you are short factors of $2$, you can supply them.  To supply two more, just multiply by $4$.  To supply $n$ factors, multiply by $4 \ \ \lceil \frac n2 \rceil $ times

Comment: What I don't need ? @ross

Comment: The question asks for the *least* multiplier. If $n$ is odd, multiplying $\lceil n/2\rceil$ times by $4$ "wastes" a factor of $2$. Can we exclude that a few clever multidigit numbers with 4s and 7s wastes less? Well, the only way to waste less and be a multiple of $2^n$ is to be equal to $2^n$. But the trailing two digits of $2^n$ are never $44$ or $74$. Hence indeed repeate multiplication by $4$ is optimum

Comment: The ability to multiply by $4$ multiple times to get lots of trailing zeros.  Given a number with a factor $5^n$ you can find a single number composed only of $4$'s and $7$'s that has a factor $2^n$.  Otherwise $7$ plays no part in this problem-you just multiply by $n/2$ factors of $4$

Comment: But to maximise the trailing zeroes and minimise the number (say in $125$), I do need to multiply 4 two times!

Comment: Yes, but I thought interesting that you could do it with one multiplication by $744$.  That is not the minimum product, but it is a single multiply

Comment: But I also need the answer to be the "minimum" number  with "maximum" trailing zeroes!

Comment: OK, I'll take that out.

Comment: Are you sure we need to multiply with only 4 and other numbers containing 4 and 7 play no role at all ?

Comment: Yes.  The smallest number containing three factors of $2$ and composed of only $4$ and $7$ is $744$.  You can get four factors of $2$ from $4 \times 4$, which is much smaller.